# Amazon app store accessible for china users?

Tags: android, app-store, amazon-appstore

We need to post our android application to china users other than Google play store which is blocked for china users.

So we thought of Amazon app store, but there is no confirmation that the amazon appstore is accessible for china users?

Kindly let me confirm about Amazon app store for china users.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to US, UK, Germany, France, Italy and Spain (Mentioned in the Wikipedia article), Amazon Android Appstore was recently released also in Japan.

And during a project on which I am working, it seems that it will also be in China... (I found references to China in the Amazon Appstore app), so we have to wait and see.

Comment: what is the cost?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon [launched their App Store in China](http://www.engadget.com/2013/05/06/amazon-appstore-china/) at the beginning of May 2013.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Amazon Appstore isn't available in China, and is only available in select countries.

From Wikipedia:

> The Amazon Appstore is a mobile application store for the Google
>   Android operating system and was opened on March 22, 2011. Available
>   in US, UK, Germany, France, Italy and Spain only.

There are certain app stores that are available in China, [the answer from your other question lists some of these.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645529/1700486)

**Edit:**

As Thilo mentions, the Amazon Appstore is now available in China.

Comment: Outdated answer. Amazon launched their App Store in China at the beginning of May 2013.

Answer (score 1):

There is also SlideMe that is a global store (also available in China, with localized client!) that has a feature for Local Apps to see local apps providing you set the settings to that specific country &/or language.

You can find more details on their site, http://slideme.org , they even updated their mobile client just a couple of weeks ago.